# Push viewcontroller not working

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, ios7.1

I have added subiews like this into my `navigationController`

`[self.navigationController.view addSubview:originanddesview];`

then inside this `originanddesview` I have a button to push another view controller

that action is like this

`

```
-(IBAction)ClickLocationButton:(id)sender
   {
       NSLog(@"Called");

       SearchGoogleLocationViewController *vwcontroller=[[SearchGoogleLocationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchGoogleLocationViewController" bundle:nil];
      [self.navigationController pushViewController:vwcontroller animated:YES];
  }
```

`

My problem is I cant see it push to that particular `viewcontroller`. But if I remove that `originanddesview` from the superview. I can see the pushed viewcontroller has already been loaded. How can I solve this problem. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this, Just remove the top view at the bottom of the push

`

```
-(IBAction)ClickLocationButton:(id)sender
   {
     NSLog(@"Called");

     SearchGoogleLocationViewController *vwcontroller=[[SearchGoogleLocationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchGoogleLocationViewController" bundle:nil];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:vwcontroller animated:YES];
     [originanddesview removefromSuperview];
  }
```

`

When u coming back from that `Viewcontroller` you will have to add that removed view into your `navigationController` back.